# Python の Bokeh で作成するグラフで、凡例とツールチップの表示を対応させたい

Tags: python, bokeh

Bokehを使って人口推移のグラフを作成しています。
以下のコードを読み込むとグラフが表示され、右側に凡例が表示されます。
ここでは `g`で定義している、凡例にある都市の名前と `tooltips`の表示を対応させたいのですが、方法がわかりません。
具体的に言うと、ここでは紫の棒グラフとして表示される"Kyoto"のデータにカーソルを当てた時、"Kyoto"のデータであることがわかるように表示したいのです。

プログラミングは始めたばかりなので、説明が分かりにくい、言葉の使い方を間違えているなどあるかもしれませんが、
どなたかご教示していただけると嬉しいです！

以下がコードになります。

```py
datak1=[59,67,76,108,108,99,110,120,128,136,141,146,147,147,146,146,146,147,147]
datak2=[60,64,78,91,96,60,80,98,111,121,128,136,136,141,147,142,149,152,154]
datas1=[10,14,16,19,20,25,31,42,52,79,101,124,140,154,167,175,182,188,191]
datak3=[2,5,10,15,30,25,31,44,63,85,97,101,104,108,117,120,124,132,142]
dataf=[9,14,22,29,30,32,39,54,64,74,85,100,108,116,123,128,134,140,146]
datah=[16,19,27,31,34,22,28,35,43,50,54,85,89,104,108,110,112,115,117]
datas2=[11,14,19,21,22,29,34,37,42,48,54,61,66,70,91,97,100,102,104]
datas3=[3,5,6,8,11,22,24,32,37,48,60,72,78,82,90,96,102,117,122]
data=[datak1,datak2,datas1,datak3,dataf,datah,datas2,datas3]
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_notebook, show
output_notebook()
from bokeh.palettes import d3
from bokeh.models import Legend
from bokeh.models.tools import HoverTool

x = range(len(data[0]))
g = ['T9','T14','S5','S10','S15','S22','S25','S30','S35','S40','S45','S50','S55','S60','H2','H7','H12','H17','H22']
z = ["Kyoto","Kobe","Sapporo","Kawasaki","Fukuoka","Hiroshima","Sendai","Saitama"] 

p = figure(x_range=g,toolbar_location="right",tools=[HoverTool()],
           sizing_mode="stretch_width",max_width=700, plot_height=250, 
           tooltips="In '@x' @z has @y million people",
          title='The Population Transition of Japanese City',
           x_axis_label='Year in Japanese Calender',
           y_axis_label='Population',
           width=800,height=350)
p.line(g, data[0], line_color='purple', legend_label= "Kyoto")
p.line(g, data[1], line_color='green', legend_label="Kobe")
p.line(g, data[2], line_color="yellow", legend_label="Sapporo")
p.line(g, data[3], line_color="orange", legend_label="Kawasaki")
p.line(g, data[4], line_color="gray", legend_label="Fukuoka")
p.line(g, data[5], line_color="red", legend_label="Hiroshima" )
p.line(g, data[6], line_color="pink", legend_label="Sendai")
p.line(g, data[7], line_color="Brown", legend_label="Saitama")

p.legend.location = "center"
p.legend.title = 'The Name of City'
p.legend.title_text_font_style = "bold"
p.legend.title_text_font_size = "15px"
p.add_layout(p.legend[0], "right")

show(p)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.tools import HoverTool, CustomJSHover

data = [[59, 67, 76, 108, 108, 99, 110, 120, 128, 136, 141, 146, 147, 147, 146, 146, 146, 147, 147],
        [60, 64, 78,  91,  96, 60,  80,  98, 111, 121, 128, 136, 136, 141, 147, 142, 149, 152, 154],
        [10, 14, 16,  19,  20, 25,  31,  42,  52,  79, 101, 124, 140, 154, 167, 175, 182, 188, 191],
        [ 2,  5, 10,  15,  30, 25,  31,  44,  63,  85,  97, 101, 104, 108, 117, 120, 124, 132, 142],
        [ 9, 14, 22,  29,  30, 32,  39,  54,  64,  74,  85, 100, 108, 116, 123, 128, 134, 140, 146],
        [16, 19, 27,  31,  34, 22,  28,  35,  43,  50,  54,  85,  89, 104, 108, 110, 112, 115, 117],
        [11, 14, 19,  21,  22, 29,  34,  37,  42,  48,  54,  61,  66,  70,  91,  97, 100, 102, 104],
        [ 3,  5,  6,   8,  11, 22,  24,  32,  37,  48,  60,  72,  78,  82,  90,  96, 102, 117, 122]]

g = [ 'T9', 'T14',  'S5', 'S10', 'S15', 'S22', 'S25', 'S30', 'S35', 'S40',
     'S45', 'S50', 'S55', 'S60',  'H2',  'H7', 'H12', 'H17', 'H22']
cities = ['Kyoto', 'Kobe', 'Sapporo', 'Kawasaki', 'Fukuoka', 'Hiroshima', 'Sendai', 'Saitama'] 
colors = ['purple', 'green', 'yellow', 'orange', 'gray', 'red', 'pink', 'brown']

x_custom = CustomJSHover(code=f'''
    const g = {g}
    return "" + g[special_vars.segment_index]
''')
p = figure(x_range=g, toolbar_location='right', tools=[HoverTool(formatters={'@x': x_custom})],
           sizing_mode='stretch_width',max_width=700, max_height=250,
           tooltips="In '@x{custom}' @cities has $y million people",
           title='The Population Transition of Japanese City',
           x_axis_label='Year in Japanese Calender', y_axis_label='Population',
           width=800, height=350)

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=[g]*len(data), y=data, color=colors, cities=cities))
p.multi_line(xs='x', ys='y', line_color='color', legend_field='cities', source=source)

p.legend.location = 'center'
p.legend.title = 'The Name of City'
p.legend.title_text_font_style = 'bold'
p.legend.title_text_font_size = '15px'
p.add_layout(p.legend[0], 'right')

show(p)
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: ありがとうございます！